# "Undefined index: preview_image_style"

Tags: media

I have this error message, which I know is related to the [multiupload_filefield_widget  module](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget). If I disable this module, the message disappear.

> Notice: Undefined index: preview_image_style in `image_field_widget_process()` (line 381 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-site.com/modules/image/image.field.inc).

I found this issue][2](http://drupal.org/node/1142382) which mention this message but isn't fixed yet.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message doesn't show up if you go to the image field settings and, under *Image preview style*, select a value that actually exist or *None*.
For some reason, there are several values in that field that don't match with any file in the filesystem; when the code checks this, it finds no such version of the image and emits an error.